# React: Filtrar para obtener solamente los valores duplicados de un Array

Tags: array, json, reactjs

En este Array obtengo todos los idCategoria de **"answersTo"**, algunos duplicados. Necesito filtrar para que me devuelva solamente esto, los duplicados. Normalmente filtraría si tengo dato para comparar, pero aquí no.

```
{
   previewData.map((getPrev: any, index: any) =>
     getPrev.answers.map((getAns: any) => {
       getAns.answersTo.map((getAnsTo: any) =>
         console.log("data", getAnsTo.idCategoria)
       );
     })
   );
 }
```

Existe alguna manera de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que aplicar un filtro dentro de answersTo para que te devuelva aquellos que aparezcan en el Array más de una vez:

```
const answersTo = [{id:1, n:2}, {id:2, n:3}, {id:3, n:3}, {id:1, n:2}, {id:2, n:3}, {id:2, n:3}];
const arrDuplicados = answersTo.filter(obtenerDuplicados);

function obtenerDuplicados(ans, index, arr) {
    return arr.filter(elem => elem.id===ans.id).length>1;
}
```

Comment: @Alid gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo answersTo.filter(obtenerDuplicados) necesita unos parámetros, quizá?

Comment: @rafa_pe los parámetros los pasa automáticamente la función filter, donde primer indica el elemento a analizar, luego su posición y finalmente la totalidad del array a analizar. Si tienes más dudas sobre esta función puedes tener más información en la siguiente página: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. En este caso hay que crear un estado para aislar el array pero funciona. Una cuestión más, en el caso de querer los NO duplicados, el sistema sería similar?

Comment: Si, el sistema es muy similar, solo tienes que editar la funcion obtenerDuplicados para que el filter devuelva true solo en los objetos que no esten duplicados o sea que su length sea igual o más pequeña a 1. Revisa la función filter.